# Use of preposition "by" in manufacturing

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Mostly everywhere people say *"This is a product made by Some-Company"*. I've also heard people say *"This is a product of Some-Company"* and *"This is a product made in Some-Company"*. According to a sentence like *"This is a book by John Smith"* will it be correct to write:

- *"This is a product by Some-Company"*

Comment: As a US English speaker, I've never heard "This is a product made **in** Some-Company."  Do you have an example?  Usually we only use "in" for geographical locations (made *in Mexico*) or spans of time (made *in the spring*).

Comment: @stangdon Unfortunately, no. I've heard people say that. I know that mostly it's: Made in China, Made in Japan and e.t.c. I've also heard people say "made at"... This food's made at McDonald's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a BrEng speaker, "*a product by X*" sounds very strange to me. Stick to using "*a product made by X*".

Comment: Always good to back up an answer with references. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+product+by%2C+a+product+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20product%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20product%20of%3B%2Cc0